# how get elements by tag within a specific div jquerymobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I want recover list of all the elements of a div using jquery mobile,  with these properties and data fields?

because I'm going to record the data for each type in a table

like this:

```
$type_of_element=...

    switch($type_of_element)
    {
    case 'textarea':
             //Recover data of this textarea
             //Save @ table
    break;

    case 'checkbox':
             //Recover data of this checkbox
             //Save @ table2
    break; 

    ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need something like this:

```
​<div id="abc"​​​​​​​​>
    <textarea name="aaa" id="aaa"></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
​</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#abc textarea, #abc input, #abc button')​.each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element.tagName); // this outputs the tagname for each selected element
    console.log($(element).val()); // this will retrieve the value from each element
});​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wjskM/)

Comment: yes it is like that, but how can I retrieve the text contained in the area of chqu'une or checkbox?

Comment: I don't understand the question - what do you mean by an area of checkbox? checkboxes do not have areas...

Comment: I believe he means the `value` attribute of an `input`, or the content of a `textarea`

Comment: I want to retrieve the text contains each element